# Как Стандарт C++ регламентирует правильное использование malloc()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, malloc, new

Скажите, пожалуйста, для каких типов в `C++` достаточно использования `malloc()`, вместо `new()`?

Я спрашиваю, потому что, согласно правилам `C++`, если мы выделяем память (при помощи `malloc()` и родственных функций), то это не означает, что в выделенной памяти существует объект.

Например:

```
Object*const object = reinterpret_cast<Object*const>(malloc(sizeof(Object)));
```

У меня есть подозрения, что приведенный выше код может нарушать `Правила Строгих Псевдонимов` (`Strict Aliasing Rules`), потому что никакого объекта типа `Object` по указанному адресу не существует, там просто существует кусок памяти, размер и выравнивание которого достаточны для размещения там объекта типа `Object`. У меня даже есть сомнения в том, что запись в `object` полученного адреса является законной операцией.

И я подозреваю, что мы должны сделать так:

```
void*const mem = malloc(sizeof(Object));
Object*const object = new(mem) Object();
```

Почему? Потому что в `C` есть концепция `действующего типа`. Мы можем записать в `сырую` память что-то и таким образом изменить действующий тип. Но в `C++` такой концепции нет, но есть концепция `динамического типа`. Очевидно, что динамический тип устанавливается функциями динамического размещения, в число которых `malloc()` (и родственные ей функции) не входят.

Скажите пожалуйста, прав ли я, и если нет, то в чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ваш первый пример вообще не компайлится. `error: cannot call constructor ‘Object::Object’ directly`

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправил пример. Судя по всему, `C++` вообще не позволяет вызывать конструкторы вручную. И это выглядит весьма неожиданно, ведь вызывать деструктор вручную - можно.

Answer (score 7):

По правилам языка, только new создает объект. Поэтому, если Вы создаете через вызов malloc вручную, компилятор законно имеет право считать, что объект не был создан и делать оптимизации/предположения на основании этого. Но все так часто использовали подобный паттерн, что ни один компилятор не делал такого. Более того, даже сейчас есть [предложения](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) считать, что malloc "создает объект" (объект как сущность, но вызывать конструктор он конечно не будет).

Мне честно больше нравится второй способ. А первый похож на странный хак и я не знаю, когда он может понадобится для сложных объектов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107345/discussion-on-answer-by-kovadim---c---).

Answer (score 2):

[Опытные специалисты](https://www.viva64.com/ru/w/v630/) считают такое использование `malloc` ошибочным. 
Я со своей стороны рекомендую не использовать `malloc`/`free` в коде на `C++` - легко перемешать их, и, к примеру, удалить память, выделенную `malloc` при помощи `delete`, что приведет к UB с печальными последствиями.

Answer (score 0):

Два условия:

1. отсутствие конструкторов и декструктора;
2. допустимость всех возможных значений.
   И стандарт здесь не причём, это простая логика: malloc отличается тем, что не вызывает конструктор вообще никак не иницаилизирует выделенную память, то есть в ней будет мусор, а парная к ней free не вызывает деструктор. А вот стандарт как раз разрешает выделять всегда и как угодно, но требует после любого выделения памяти без вызова конструкторов вызывать placement new, а перед освобождением явно вызывать деструктор.