# Указатель на массив посредством malloc

Tags: c++, c, malloc

определил переменную:

```
double(*p0)[2];
```

а теперь как мне её динамически инициализировать посредством `malloc` (именно `malloc`, а не `new`)?

Comment: Нету у `malloc` средств, нищая она... :) Что вы хотите? Выделить память для массива из двух `double`? А как бы вы ее "инициализировали посредством `new`", можете показать?

Comment: @Harry, точно ? выходит только статически можно, а я ломаю голову несколько часов )))

Comment: @Harry , при помощи new так можно :  double(*p)[2] = new double[1][2];

Comment: OK, отлично - итак, вы выделили **сколько** памяти? В байтах? Да, кстати! а работать с `p` вы как планируете?

Comment: @Harry, а хрен их знает, вот это sizeof(double[1][2]); дает 16. значит выделил на 2 дубля.

Comment: @Harry, да никак не планирую пока,   я не очень понимаю природу самого указателя на массив - double(*p0)[2].

Comment: @Harry работать выходит можно как с двухмерным массивом: p[0][0]=3.14

Comment: Так, отлично. Вы выделили 2 `double`. Ну так давайте вы выделите их через `malloc` - `double(*p)[2] = malloc(sizeof(double[1][2]));`. Если вы компилируете в C++ - то нужно приведение типа - `double(*p)[2] = (double(*)[2])malloc(sizeof(double[1][2]));`. Попробуйте!

Comment: @Harry . круто , а я думал, что так нельзя : sizeof(double[1][2]).

Comment: Да обращайтесь, если нужно :)

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, еще можно так: `double(*p)[2] = (__typeof__(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));` / Вообще, можете запомнить __typeof__() и sizeof() это весьма полезные в С++ штуки

Comment: @avp а зачем пользоваться  __typeof__ если есть без подчеркивания ? в чем разница ?

Comment: @АндрейГуренков, с подчеркиваниями большее количество компиляторов понимает (вообще-то, насколько помню, typeof это изначально GNU-расширение, остальные потом подхватили)

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминая старый спор, переношу в ответ комментарий Harry:

В C -

```
double(*p)[2] = malloc(sizeof(double[1][2]));
```

В С++ нужно добавить приведение типа:

```
double(*p)[2] = (double(*)[2])malloc(sizeof(double[1][2]));
```

Comment: Строго говоря, в C++ одного только приведения указателя, полученного от `malloc` не достаточно для создания объекта. Работа с указателем `p` чревата неопределённым поведением. См.: [Как Стандарт C++ регламентирует правильное использование malloc()?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1114517)

Comment: @wololo Здесь нет *объекта*

Comment: Не понял, что вы хотели сказать своим комментарием. Поясню свою позицию. `std::malloc` предоставляет хранилище (storage), в котором можно разместить какой-нибудь объект. Но сама `std::malloc` никаких объектов в этом хранилище не размещает. Указатель на такое хранилище (в котором нет объекта) можно использовать ограниченно. В частности, поведение программы не определено при касте такого указателя в любой другой указатель, кроме `cv void*`, `cv char*`, `cv unsigned char*`, `cv std::byte*`. См.: [basic.life/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6).

Comment: @Mikhailo, интересно вот так работает : double(*p)[2] = malloc(sizeof(double[1][2])); а я думал , что надо переводить из void * в double(*)[2] (читаю старый K&R)